# Don't draw node outside of parent node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a SpriteKit game on iOS using Swift (although an Objective-C answer would still help), and I have an SKSpriteNode whose parent is another SKSpriteNode. However, I only want to sub-node to be drawn when it is within the frame of the parent node. So for example, I have:

```
let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
let skView = self.view as! SKView
skView.presentScene(scene)

let superNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
scene.addChild(superNode)

let subNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 0.5, height: 0.5))
superNode.addChild(subNode)
```

It looks as follows:[image: 1]]

However, if I move `subNode` to (1.5, 1.5):

```
subNode.position = CGPoint(1.5, 1.5)
```

Then `subNode` is visually outside of `superNode`, but it is still drawn:
[image]

However, I would like it to look as follows:
[image]

As a further example, if I set `subNode`'s position to (1.0, 1.0), it looks as follows:
[image]

But I would like it to look like this:
[image]

How do I get it to only be drawn when it is within `superNode`? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks:)

Comment: So basically you want the red to be contained within the blue frame? Look up SKCropNode. As far as I know, you can't reproduce the effect of only partial of the node appearing when part of it is off the parent node except cropping.

Comment: I agree with @JozemiteApps , the SKCropNode with a mask is the solution